# What is the proper way to use commas when addressing two or more people by placing their names at the start of the sentence?

Tags: commas, names, business-language

I frequently need to address multiple people in writing at work. This is usually done in a way that makes it convenient to *at* them all at once.

E.g.

> @dale, @emily, please take a look at this and, if you approve, transition it to the next step.

> Ben, Steve, I'd appreciate it if you could re-review this.

What's the correct way to use commas (or conjunctions?) to address these people when there are more than one of them?

Comment: Your "list" of addressees only contains 2 elements anyway, but the default in English is to include the conjunction ***and*** between the ***last*** 2 elements in any such list. Compare with *My lords, ladies, **and** gentlemen,...* as normally used to address an audience. In practice people don't usually bother about "grammar / syntax" for your cited context (office emails) - but to the extent this is a meaningful question, you should address your audience as *[Hi,] Ben **and** Steve, [this is the text I'm writing to you].* Or *Addressee1, Addressee2[,] and Addressee3,...* if there are more.

Comment: (That's an optional "Oxford comma" before the penultimate item in the list.)

Comment: Well shoot, that makes sense! Why not write it as an answer?

Comment: I voted to close a "Primarily Opinion-Based". As things stand, I still agree 100% with what I wrote above, but if anyone else were to pitch in with some alternative approach I might change my mind anyway!